# How to show loading spinner of LGButton before executing function on click?

Tags: ios, swift, button, time, delay

I was using https://github.com/loregr/LGButton . I got the button to trigger a function etc but how do I use the loading spinner UI of this library? Once I enable it too, it only shows for a couple milliseconds since on button click the function is triggered fast

```
@IBAction func theFunction(_ sender: LGButton) {
       
        let alertView = SCLAlertView()
        alertView.addButton("Y button", target: self, selector: #selector(self.generateNewNumber))
        alertView.addButton("X Button", target: self, selector: #selector(self.zfunction))

        alertView.showSuccess("", subTitle: ""])

    }
  
    
    @IBOutlet var instanceofLGButton: LGButton!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black 
        instanceofLGButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.learning(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Thank you. The relevant section of code is above.

Comment: Do you wanna show spinner in LGButton just like [TransitionButton](https://github.com/AladinWay/TransitionButton)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `isLoading` parameter to `true`, it will show spinner.

```
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: LGButton) {
        sender.isLoading = true
        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
            sender.isLoading = false
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This works. I tried using only DispatchQueue without.main.asyncAfter in the exact same way with the DO SOMETHING action enclosed but without sender.isLoading. From where is isLoading a function. Is it in the Apple Docs. Could you link it? Thanks @delavega66 Where did you get the isLoading from?

Comment: No, it's a third party library.. I got it from `LGButton` Example project.